# Danger for hot air balloon if someone jumps out

Tags: balloon, skydiving

I recently saw a video that I believe was filmed in Turkey where a skydiver was prevented from jumping out of a hot air balloon by the operator/pilot.

[Man tries to jump out of a hot air balloon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXPuOA3Bkh4) (YouTube video)

His rationale for stopping the jumper was:

1. the balloon could go out of control and fly up unexpectedly
2. he could lose his licensing.

He goes into a long explanation of the dangers of someone unexpectedly jumping out but something seems off to me. I have done balloon jumps and the basket is incredibly stable when people jump. The basket and people must weight a couple thousand pounds so I can't see how a person with a parachute could have the dramatic effect that is described in his explanation. I am in no way arguing that he should have been allowed to jump, just saying I am not buying the potential danger described.

Does the description of the danger hold any air?

Comment: Re "His rationale for stopping the jumper was 1) the balloon could go out of control and fly up unexpectedly, 2) he could lose his licensing."-- I haven't watched the video, but it seems from this description that there should have been more of a pre-flight discussion.  What, was the existence of the parachute and the intention to jump not revealed until the flight was already underway?  ??!!??

Comment: After watching the video-- perhaps he had the chute hidden under a jacket or coat that he removed in the middle of a flight?  (Edit) sounds like they were at around 3000' AGL when this all happened--

Comment: In the UK, the ANO says "the dropping of persons by parachute and which is made under and in accordance with the terms of a parachuting permission granted by the CAA under article 90"  so you'd need a permit for a parachute jump.  Turkey is a member of the ICAO so I'd guess something similar applies there.

Comment: The balloon pilot should have just yanked the wannabe skydiver's D-ring so the chute would fall out in a clump on the floor of the balloon basket!  (I guess the springy thing in the pilot chute could have been a problem though  :(  )   Maybe in the future all balloon pilots should carry a bicycle cable lock to lock the skydiving rig to the balloon basket; that would be a way to instantly end the issue --

Comment: @quietflyer That adds much more danger than it takes away. If he was able to get a chute out while in the basket there is no telling what would happen. If he was able to pull his pilot chute all the way out, the main parachute would probably just fall out in the deployment bag. If he pulled the reserve handle, it could get ugly as that is spring loaded and could potentially inflate. For the most part D-rings are going the way of the dinosaur being replaced by padded handles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The basket and people must weight a couple thousand pounds so I can't
> see how a person with a parachute could have the dramatic effect that
> is described in his explanation. I am in no way arguing that he should
> have been allowed to jump, just saying I am not buying the potential
> danger described.
>
> Does the description of the danger hold any air?

The explanation starting at 2:30 in the video (

) is enlightening.  By "parachute" he is referring to the round top of the balloon which is only held in place by some velcro, plus the upward pressure of the hot air which forces the "parachute" upwards against the load tapes.  Normally the "parachute" is only pulled slightly downward occasionally on one side to spill a small amount of hot air, until after touchdown when it is pulled completely down to deflate the envelope as soon as possible to prevent the wind from dragging the balloon along on the ground.  A downward aerodynamic load on the top of the balloon due to an abnormally high ascent rate could dislodge the "parachute" entirely and let all the hot air out.  This is why skydivers should normally only be allowed to exit when the balloon has zero vertical speed, or is in a descent.  Likewise for hang glider drops.

The "parachute" or "parachute valve" can be seen on a diagram on this web page: https://hotairflight.com/blog/parts-of-a-hot-air-balloon?expand_article=1

This link has some interesting reading about skydiving from balloons:  https://www.droplyne.com/skydivers

Comment: Last link is really more about logistics than flight dynamics/safety but still is an interesting (and kind of funny) read-- some more links could surely be found that more directly address the flight dynamics/safety issues--

Comment: So if: 1) The balloon is moving upwards. 2) The person jumping is a large percentage of the total weight to have maximum effect(small balloon and basket with few passengers etc.) -- a danger exists. I believe the pilot in the video may have been overstating the danger but he probably did that to scare off any additional morons that would want to try this without permission.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the danger is real. A hot air balloon basket weighs very little, and can often be easily carried by two people. I haven't seen your video but the total payload can be less then 750 pounds so having two hundred pounds of ballast jump out can make a real difference, causing the balloon to gain a lot of height and potentially putting it into very different wind conditions.

At the end of the day, everything that happens is the pilots responsibility. If they are unsure of any aspect of the flight, they must take the least risky option.

Comment: This goes against my experience as stated in my question.

Comment: Even if the payload plus basket weighs only 750 lb, the entire aircraft must weigh roughly double that to stay buoyant (it must displace 750 lb of atmosphere, with something not much lighter).  200 / 1500 isn't quite so dramatic.

Comment: Plus the weight of the fabric "envelope" is not trivial either-- often around 200 pounds according to this source https://www.balloon-rides.com/atics-facts.htm#

Comment: Re "(it must displace 750 lb of atmosphere, with something not much lighter)" -- if the buoyant lift is to be x pounds (say 750) and density rato of the displacing gas (air) to the surrounding gas (air) is y which you are suggesting is not much less than 1, then doesn't the total weight z of the displacing gas (air) have to be such that (z/y) -z = x?  If y is not much less than one, then the weight of the displacing gas must be *much* larger than x.  Source cited above lists an envelope volume of 77,000 cubic feet to lift 550 pounds of ballon, plus the occupants which might typcially be 2.

Comment: @SDH - I have seen the video now, and the jumper was being an utter assh*le. When the pilot in charge says no, that means no, end of conversation. Unless you have commanded a balloon, you are not really in a position to judge what "stable" means. If you have done balloon jumps, have you ever been the last to jump and have you noticed what was happening to your variometer? The movement might not be rapid (few things in a balloon are) but it is significant and impacts all aspects of flight, including its safety.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune (ctd) -- this source https://seattleballooning.com/how-hot-air-balloons-work/ suggests a typical max operating temp of 250-300 degrees F.  That would be the temp at the air at the *top* of the envelope only.  But assuming for simplicity that the *entire* envelope is full of 250-degree air and we have 77,000 cubic feet of dry air at sea-level pressure, then we still have 0.055907 * 77000 =4300 pounds of air!  (Density calculated by thiscalculator https://www.calctool.org/atmospheric-thermodynamics/air-density .)

Comment: (Ctd) So, total weight is *way* more than double the uninflated weight + occupants!  That helps to explain how it can *ever* be safe to allow a skydive, or a hang glider drop (google it for some cool videos!)

Comment: Please stop guessing and do some research. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ofcl8V9Dws

Comment: That's not research, that's a class exercise where the total mass or weight is specified up front.  My point was simply that C.G.'s comment hugely underestimated the total weight of a 2-3 occupant balloon, by incorrectly suggesting that the total weight including weight of air in envelope should be about double the weight of empty envelope+basket+occupants.  Also see links to actual figures for typical envelope volumes within comments.

Comment: @PaulSmith I agree the jumper in the linked video was an ass but my question has nothing to do with him. I have jumped multiple times but never the last person to leave. At no point have I ever experienced any sudden motion or instability that the pilot mentions in his explanation. Are you speaking from experience when you say the movement 'is significant'?

Comment: (1/2) It is not sudden, nothing in a balloon is. In the 'exercise' I linked to, when 40Kg ballast was released (about half the weight of a jumper),  a 1.5m/s descent (about 300 feet per minute down) was turned into a 0.3m/s ascent (~60feet per minute up) over a period of 5 seconds. That is quite gentle, but definitely significant. Double the ballast loss, and do it when the operator has not planned for it and is not expecting it, and you quickly move into safety of flight issues.

Comment: (2/2) If this ass had actually done nearly as many jumps as he claimed, then he should have come across these issues in the past. The fact that he continues arguing with the pilot makes me question his experience. I am not a jumper myself but have heard enough stories of planned jumps being cancelled by the pilot because the conditions did not support a safe release to know that unplanned jumps are just not on.

Comment: Video linked above has only limited application to this topic.  Did you notice that the balloon was initially experiencing a constant downward *acceleration* (not velocity), and likewise ended up rising with constant upward *acceleration* after the ballast was released?  And there's no consideration given to air drag?  And the 460 kg or 1014 pound balloon is much lighter than any hot-air balloon that can carry more than one person, if we include the weight of the air in the envelope as per my earlier comments.  Sure it gives a *slight* feel for what happens when we drop some weight but...

Comment: Sorry quite flyer, but you are off on a tangent again, what has drag got to do with anything? Watch the video again, an upward acceleration is required to turn a downward velocity into an upward velocity. An 80Kg jumper would result in acceleration that would cause a significant increase in upward velocity. When unplanned, that can introduce a significant flight control and potential safety issue which was the core of the original question.

Comment: @PaulSmith -- answered in chat -- https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65265222#65265222 , https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151743/discussion-between-quiet-flyer-and-paul-smith

Comment: @SDH -- Re "At no point have I ever experienced any sudden motion or instability that the pilot mentions in his explanation" -- keep in mind that even a *small* vertical acceleration (which will be essentially impossible to "feel"), if *sustained*, will eventually lead to a *high* vertical velocity.  As discussed in the chat link, air drag tends to eventually retard the acceleration rate, but still, that basic observation, combined w/ some details given in the other answer, may help highlight the possible issues.  Also some atmospheric profiles tend to promote instability more than others --